# Error when stopping neo4j 2.0.0 M06 from ksh script on rhel6.2 server

Tags: neo4j, ksh

My script contains the following code:

```
bin_dir="/export/neo4j-community-2.0.0-M06/bin"
...snip...
  `$bin_dir/neo4j stop`
  stoprc=$?
  if [ "${stoprc}" -ne "0" ] ; then
    echo "Error stopping neo4j.  Please check that it is running."
    exit ${stoprc}
  fi
```

The result is

```
Stopping: not found [No such file or directory]
Return code is 127
```

Here is output from ksh -x of this script.

```
+ /export/neo4j-community-2.0.0-M06/bin/neo4j stop
+ Stopping Neo4j Server '[13634]....' done
restore_graph.ksh[42]: Stopping: not found [No such file or directory]
+ stoprc=127
```

But when I run ="/export/neo4j-community-2.0.0-M06/bin/neo4j stop" from the command line I have no issues:

```
: /export/neo4j-community-2.0.0-M06/bin/neo4j stop
Stopping Neo4j Server [12975].... done
: echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is the problem

```
`$bin_dir/neo4j stop`
```

neo4j stops, but then because of the backticks, you execute the *output* of `neo4j stop` as a command.

Remove those backticks.